# Not sure where to post a question about finding a mentor

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am a college student looking for a mentor and I am not sure how I should go about doing it. I want to post this question but I do not know where to post it or even if this is the right forum for this question.

Comment: A minor nitpick: The SO/SE network of sites is made up of Q&A sites and not forums. An important difference regarding the content that will fit on the various sites.

Comment: @Bart, so is my question more for a forum? If so, do you have any suggestions for where to post it?

Comment: No, that's not what I meant and I honestly can't suggest anything beyond what @blahdiblah has already stated. You just used the word "forum" in your question. That's all I was hinting at in my off-topic remark.

Comment: Hi Emily! Welcome to Stack Overflow. As Some Helpful Commenter has pointed out below, there are a number of sites in the Stack Exchange network that might suit your needs. I hope you take a few moments to check them out, they're good sites with the same values as Stack Overflow. :)

Comment: try http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: Maybe in chat somewhere?

Answer (score 7):

This is not the place.

I'd recommend finding a local hackerspace or asking your professors if they have any advice about where/how to look.

Comment: Thank you, I will take my question elsewhere :D

Comment: Technically, this answer is incorrect. She was wondering which site might be best for her to ask a question about mentorship. Telling her that she should ask in Analog Life is good advice, but also ignores the number of other sites ([academia.se], [workplace.se], etc.) where she could ask her questions. Just a little nitpick. :)

Answer (score 6):

If you were a graduate student I'd recommend [academia.stackexchange.com](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) since they do have [6 questions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mentoring) tagged mentoring.

If your were an entrepreneur I'd recommend [answers.onstartups](http://answers.onstartups.com/) which has [20 questions](http://answers.onstartups.com/questions/tagged/mentor) tagged mentor

If you were looking for mentoring in the workplace I'd suggest [workplace.stackexchange.com](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) but they don't have any mentoring questions yet.

That said before asking a question on any of these be sure to visit the the site faq to make sure that you are in the right place before you do post.